# Kinect: getting the joint coordinates (x,y) in meters

Tags: c++, visual-c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

Hi I understand that under the official documentation from Microsoft is that the cameraspacepoints obtained are already expressed in meters. However, I'm still uncertain if the values are in meters as the values are varying in 9 digits or more and positive and negative at times.

Can anybody explain to me what these values are and are they already in meters?

[Function to process body (placed the output of the joint[j].position in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMLcA.jpg)

[image]

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvFvZ.jpg)

[image]

Do let me know if you all require additional information. I apologize as I'm new to kinect. Btw, this is kinect v2!

Answer (score 1):

Each Joint has a `Position` property, which is a [`CameraSpecePoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1). A CameraSpacePoint object has three properties, `X`, `Y` and `Z`, which are `float32` and are expressed in **meters**.

As explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1):

> Camera space refers to the 3D coordinate system used by Kinect. The coordinate system is defined as follows:
>
> - The origin (x=0, y=0, z=0) is located at the center of the IR sensor on Kinect
> - X grows to the sensor’s left
> - Y grows up (note that this direction is based on the sensor’s tilt)
> - Z grows out in the direction the sensor is facing
>     1 unit = 1 meter

Note also that you have used a `%d` in the [`sprintf`](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwib2v_b7bPLAhVCkA8KHY8GA1QQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Freference%2Fcstdio%2Fsprintf%2F&usg=AFQjCNEEaGblcLH4jeHkBfrdFh9K0T_Xkw&sig2=qpdajKsgzVqMfL7-kOl3aA) method to print a float value, while `%d` should be only used for signed decimal integer (see the table in [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)). If you want to print X, Y and Z values, you must use `%f`; so your `sprintf` should become like this:

```
sprint(abc, "Head is at %f on X-axis\n", joints[j].Position.X);
```